# ts-loader complaining about unused variables that don't exist in the code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

Recently I've been running into the issue that, whenever I put a console.log statement in my code, I get certain unused variable errors. For example, this file:

```
import { ConfigApiResponse } from "../models/configApi.interfaces";
import axios from "axios";

export const fetchConfig = (baseUrl: string) => {
  console.log(baseUrl);
  return axios.get<ConfigApiResponse>(`${baseUrl}/config/application.json`);
};
```

Gives me the following errors, because of the console.log() statement:

```
ERROR in /Users/daniel/workspace/onewelcome/consent-ui/src/common/api/configApi.ts
9:34505-34510
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/daniel/workspace/onewelcome/consent-ui/src/common/api/configApi.ts(9,34506)
      TS6133: 'oo_ts' is declared but its value is never read.
ts-loader-default_e3b0c44298fc1c14

ERROR in /Users/daniel/workspace/onewelcome/consent-ui/src/common/api/configApi.ts
9:34561-34566
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/daniel/workspace/onewelcome/consent-ui/src/common/api/configApi.ts(9,34562)
      TS6133: 'oo_te' is declared but its value is never read.
ts-loader-default_e3b0c44298fc1c14

webpack 5.75.0 compiled with 2 errors in 7257 ms
```

Has anybody else experienced this issue and knows how to disable this error and allow webpack compilation?

Comment: most likely there are other transformations affecting your code before the ts-loade

Comment: How does your webpack config looks like?